# How can I get images from local storage and then display them on screen in Native Script. I am using nativescript-imagepicker and fs

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I am new to Native Script. How can I display an image from local storage? I used the nativescript-imagepicker but then, I don't know where the image is stored. I am using this code.

```js
var imagepicker = require("nativescript-imagepicker");

var context = imagepicker.create({ mode: "single" }); // use "multiple" for multiple selection

let SlcImg = ""; 

exports.imgPic = function() {
    context
    .authorize()
    .then(function() {
        return context.present();
    })
    .then(function(selection) {
        selection.forEach(function(selected) {
                SlcImg = path;
        })
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
}
```

I am trying to set the path to SlcImg. In my xml part of the app this is the code.

```
<Image src="{{imageSource}}" class="imageCss" stretch="aspectFill"></Image>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var context = imagepickerModule.create({
    mode: "single" // allow choosing single image
});
context
    .authorize()
    .then(function () {
        return context.present();
    })
    .then(function (selection) {
        console.log("Selection done:");
        setTimeout(() => {
            selection.forEach(function (selected) {
                selected.getImage().then((source) => {
                    console.log(selected.fileUri); // this is the uri you need
                });     
            });
        }, 1000);            
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

Use the fileUri. And that setTimeout is optional, in my project without that, the app screen was going blank for a second.

Comment: I know this might sound like spoon feeding the code but here is the issue. I tried using observable modules and I tried "return path" but it doesn't seem to work. How can I set this uri to image in xml. BTW , half the problem is solved. Thanks to you. I am able to console log the locations. :)

Comment: To set this uri to image in xml, just bind this data to the source property of the image.