# Nativescript imagepicker .getImage() is not a function error

Tags: nativescript

I have been trying to implement the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46817722/how-can-i-get-images-from-local-storage-and-then-display-them-on-screen-in-nativ) but keep getting the error "selected.getImage is not a function".

I have tried multiple different code examples at this point and I'm stumped.  It seems like this is a type error, but I'm not sure where I can correct this.

I am looking to select a single image and return the path to that image in order to upload to the server. I don't need to display it on the device, though that is an option I suppose.  Seems easy enough, but apparently I'm missing something.

I'm using v. 6.0.1 or the imagepicker plugin. I'd quote the code, but at this point I am using the exact example provided by Shiva Prasad in the above question.

Adding code per Max Vollmer:

```js
var context = imagepickerModule.create({
    mode: "single" // allow choosing single image
});
context
    .authorize()
    .then(function () {
        return context.present();
    })
    .then(function (selection) {
        console.log("Selection done:");
        setTimeout(() => {
            selection.forEach(function (selected) {
                selected.getImage().then((source) => {
                    console.log(selected.fileUri); // this is the uri you need
                });     
            });
        }, 1000);            
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

Comment: It still makes sense to copy the code into your question and then link to the answer for proper credit. Same goes for any relevant information from the other question. That way people can concentrate on your question without having to follow links. Also there is always the possibility that those other posts get deleted or changed in the future for whatever reason. Kudos, though, for posting a well written new question and linking to an existing one for context. And welcome to SO!

Comment: @USG did you manage to fix this? i have the same error. tried the sample code but if i implement the same context above i get the same error - i think its a dependency issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same error yesterday.

I use the fromAsset function directly on the "selected" because apparently with the new version of this plugin, "selected" is an Asset. So you got an imageSource and you can use the "saveToFile" function that will copy the Asset into a new location (get this location using fileSystemModule from TNS). Use the path of this new location for your UI, and the image will appear. You can also create a file object from this location `fileSystemModule.File.fromPath(path);`, I use for upload.

```
context
            .authorize()
            .then(function () {
                return context.present();
            })
            .then(function (selection) {
                selection.forEach(function (selected) {

                    let file;

                    if (selected._android) {

                        file = fileSystemModule.File.fromPath(selected._android);
                        //viewModel.uploadFile(file);

                    }else{

                        imageSourceModule.fromAsset(selected).then((imageSource) => {

                        const folder = fileSystemModule.knownFolders.documents().path;
                        const fileName = "Photo.png"; 
                        const path = fileSystemModule.path.join(folder, fileName);
                        const saved = imageSource.saveToFile(path, "png");

                        if (saved) {
                            console.log("Image saved successfully!");
                            file = fileSystemModule.File.fromPath(path);
                            //viewModel.uploadFile(file);
                        }else{
                            console.log("Error! - image couldnt save.");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            }).catch(function (e) {
                console.log(e);
                // process error
            });
```

**Explanation**

The uncommented snippet (`//viewModel.uploadFile(file);`), `viewModel` reference (will be different on your app) and the function: `uploadFile` for example is where you would pass the file to upload it or set it to the `image.src` etc

Make sure to declare `imageSourceModule` at the top.

```
const imageSourceModule = require("tns-core-modules/image-source");
```