# Nativescript - Property 'getImage' does not exist on type 'ImageAsset'

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am using the nativescript-imagepicker plugin and keep getting the specific error ("Property 'getImage' does not exist on type 'ImageAsset'"), by using the following code:

```
this.context.authorize()
  .then(() => {
    return this.context.present();
  })
  .then((selection) => {
    selection.forEach((selected) => {
      selected.getImage().then((imagesource) => {
        const folder = fileSystem.knownFolders.documents();
        const path = fileSystem.path.join(folder.path, milliseconds + ".png");
        const saved = imagesource.saveToFile(path , "png");
        this.newImage = path;
      });
    });
  });
```

Looking around, I found other people reporting this issue, but cannot find a solution to it. As a hint from a youtube video about the plugin, "I’ve used NS2.5 so it could be different in NS3+﻿" [video](https://youtu.be/uI5cZTC12sU) I hope it helps.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50649470/nativescript-imagepicker-getimage-is-not-a-function-error) has been posted here some time ago with no answer, but without an answer. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the API references for `ImageAsset` there is no `getImage` method. There is a method [getImageAsync](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_image_asset_.imageasset#getimageasync) which you can use.

The plugin [nativescript-imagepicker](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-imagepicker) has also introduced some breaking changes recently so you might want to align your code with the new codebase.

> Migrating from 5.x.x to 6.x.x With version 6.x.x the dependency to the
>   nativescript-ui-listview plugin is removed and for iOS the
>   QBImagePicker cocoa pod is used. Now the plugin supports some new
>   features, fixes some bugs and has a more native look in iOS. You
>   should remove any dependencies to nativescript-pro-ui,
>   nativescript-ui-listview, etc. in case you've added them in your app
>   specifically for this plugin. Also the options fileUri, doneText,
>   cancelText, albumsText, newestFirst and the methods cancel() and
>   done() are no longer applicable. The image picker now returns the
>   basic {N} ImageAsset class (and not custom asset as before). If you
>   have been using the fileUri property of the returned assets to get a
>   file path in versions prior to 6.x.x, you should refer to the
>   following issue comment for an alternative way to get the path -
>   https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-imagepicker/issues/181#issuecomment-384585293.

Answer (score 1):

Struggling to fix this for days...

This fixed it for me -

*Note the uncommented (`//viewModel.uploadFile(file);`), `viewModel` reference (will be different on your app) and the function: `uploadFile` for example is where you would pass the file to upload it or set it to the `image.src` etc

```
context
            .authorize()
            .then(function () {
                return context.present();
            })
            .then(function (selection) {
                selection.forEach(function (selected) {

                    let file;

                    if (selected._android) {

                        file = fileSystemModule.File.fromPath(selected._android);
                        //viewModel.uploadFile(file);

                    }else{

                        imageSourceModule.fromAsset(selected).then((imageSource) => {

                        const folder = fileSystemModule.knownFolders.documents().path;
                        const fileName = "Photo.png"; 
                        const path = fileSystemModule.path.join(folder, fileName);
                        const saved = imageSource.saveToFile(path, "png");

                        if (saved) {
                            console.log("Image saved successfully!");
                            file = fileSystemModule.File.fromPath(path);
                            //viewModel.uploadFile(file);
                        }else{
                            console.log("Error! - image couldnt save.");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            }).catch(function (e) {
                console.log(e);
                // process error
            });
```